# import ed25519._ed25519 works in powershell but not GAE

Tags: python, c, powershell, google-app-engine

Does anyone have suggestions as to why I am getting the error below when using GAE and not with powershell? pip install comes back with requirement is already satisfied.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "C:\Users\kunle\Documents\LAGOS_BUSINESS\ISHOPEAZYV2\iShopEazyV2WebApp\ishopeazy.py", line 21, in <module>
    from stellar_base.keypair import Keypair
  File "C:\Users\kunle\Documents\LAGOS_BUSINESS\ISHOPEAZYV2\iShopEazyV2WebApp\lib\stellar_base\keypair.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .utils import XdrLengthError, decode_check, encode_check
  File "C:\Users\kunle\Documents\LAGOS_BUSINESS\ISHOPEAZYV2\iShopEazyV2WebApp\lib\stellar_base\utils.py", line 15, in <module>
    import ed25519
  File "C:\Users\kunle\Documents\LAGOS_BUSINESS\ISHOPEAZYV2\iShopEazyV2WebApp\lib\ed25519\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .keys import (BadSignatureError, BadPrefixError,
  File "C:\Users\kunle\Documents\LAGOS_BUSINESS\ISHOPEAZYV2\iShopEazyV2WebApp\lib\ed25519\keys.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import _ed25519
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\runtime\sandbox.py", line 1093, in load_module
    raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named ed25519._ed25519
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot import [C extension modules](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27) into a GAE application. `ed25519._ed25519` is an extension module written in C.

You must find an implementation of Ed25519 that doesn't require the use of a C extension.